# How to deal with exact value types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Like if there is an interface

```js
interface IHello {
  x: 'hello';
}

function fun(obj: IHello) {
  ...
}
```

then doing this

```js
var obj = {
  x: 'hello'
};

fun(obj);
```

gives an error 
Type `string` is not assignable to type `hello`;

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: The inferred type is `{ x: string }`, do e.g. `var obj: IHello = {...}`. Note that the term is [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

Comment: You could also do `var obj = {x: 'hello'} as const;` for a narrower inference (which I think gives you the type `{readonly x: "hello"}`.